# Can someone tell me why my python loop won't work for creating a multiple choice quiz?

Tags: python, loops

Just wondering how to get this loop to run- i think it has something to do with the variables but I'm not too sure. completely new to coding

```
def question1 ():

    answer1 = input ("What is the correct answer?")
        if answer1 == "B" :
            right_answer1 = True
            print ("That is correct!")
        elif answer1 == "b" :
            right_answer1 = True
            print ("That is correct!")
        elif answer1 == " b":
            right_answer1 = True
            print("That is correct!")
        elif answer1 == " B":
            right_answer1 = True
            print("That is correct!")
        else:
            right_answer1 = False
            print ("Please try again!")
    if right_answer1 != True :
        question1()
```

Comment: Can you correct your indentation first? Its hard to tell what is within the function and what is not.

Comment: There's kinda a loop, although his poor formatting makes it hard to see.  He's looping via recursion

Comment: Sorry community...I gotta do this one thing...it's driving me crazy... @Daniel, you can replace the four tests for a correct "b" answer with just one test: "if answer1.strip().lower() == 'b':"

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do first. "My correct answer is 'b', and I want to deem the input answer correct if it is lowercase or uppercase b, with or without spaces", correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your desired code is something like this. FYI the "loop" you are referring to is called [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion). Your function is *recursively* calling itself whenever an incorrect answer is entered.

```
def question1():

    answer1 = input("What is the correct answer?")

    if answer1 == "B":
        right_answer1 = True
        print ("That is correct!")
    elif answer1 == "b" :
        right_answer1 = True
        print ("That is correct!")
    elif answer1 == " b":
        right_answer1 = True
        print("That is correct!")
    elif answer1 == " B":
        right_answer1 = True
        print("That is correct!")
    else:
        right_answer1 = False
        print ("Please try again!")

    if right_answer1 != True :
        question1()

question1()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def question():
   answer = input ("What is the correct answer?")
   if answer.upper().strip() == "B":
       print("That is correct!")
       return True
   print ("Please try again!")
   return False

while !question():
    pass
```

Comment: There is no reason to use a global variable for this. Not a good habit to use globals unless you have a good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Python 2.7

> In Python 2, raw_input() returns a string, and input() tries to run the input as a Python expression.

So if you try to pass input b would throw an error saying

NameError: name 'b' is not defined

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Use below code snippet and pass input with single or double quotes.

   def question1():

   ```
   answer1 = input("What is the correct answer?")

   if answer1 == "B" or answer1 == " B":
       right_answer1 = True
       print ("That is correct!")
   elif answer1 == "b" or answer1 == " b":
       right_answer1 = True
       print ("That is correct!")
   else:
       right_answer1 = False
       print ("Please try again!")

   if right_answer1 != True :
       question1()
   ```

   question1()
2. Use raw_input and you need not to pass quotes around input since python would convert it into string for you

replace line answer1 = input("What is the correct answer?") with

answer1 = raw_input("What is the correct answer?")

Comment: What makes you think this is the cause of the issue? Nothing in the question indicates they are using 2.7

Answer (score -1):

I see that you are very new to programming, and to python. You are almost there, but you have made a few mistakes:

1) Where is the loop?

There has to be a type of loop of type `for`/ `while`. You also need to specify a condition of starting, incrementing & ending the loop.
Following is the syntax of a loop:

```
for i in range(start, end, increment):
    # Your set of statements
```

For the while loop:

```
while condition!=True:
    # Your set of statements
```

2) You have not given proper indentation, which is very important in Python-3

So, the new program would look like:

```
def question1 ():
    right__answer1 = False
    answer1 = input ("What is the correct answer?")
    while right__answer1!=True:
        if answer1 == "B" :
            right_answer1 = True
            print ("That is correct!")
            break
        elif answer1 == "b" :
            right_answer1 = True
            print ("That is correct!")
            break
        elif answer1 == " b":
            right_answer1 = True
            print("That is correct!")
            break
        elif answer1 == " B":
            right_answer1 = True
            print("That is correct!")
            break
        else:
            right_answer1 = False
            print ("Please try again!")
question1()
```

You might actually be referring to recursion:

```
def question1 ():

    answer1 = input ("What is the correct answer?")

    if answer1 == "B" :
        right_answer1 = True
        print ("That is correct!")
    elif answer1 == "b" :
        right_answer1 = True
        print ("That is correct!")
    elif answer1 == " b":
        right_answer1 = True
        print("That is correct!")
    elif answer1 == " B":
        right_answer1 = True
        print("That is correct!")
    else:
        right_answer1 = False
        print ("Please try again!")
        question1()
question1()
```

Comment: This answer won't work.  If the user gets the answer wrong the first time, it will print "Please try again!" forever.

Comment: Both of these solutions have errors. Steve pointed out the issue with the loop. The recursive does not show the initial call to the function.

Comment: Looks like I forgot the `break` condition!! Made corrections now... Thanks for pointing it out, @Steve @Nick

Answer (score -1):

```
def question1 ():

    while True:
        answer1 = input ("What is the correct answer?")
        if (answer1.strip().lower() == 'b'):
            print("That is correct!")
            return  # or 'break'
        print("Please try again!")

question1()
```

Comment: not my down vote, but probably because this is a code-only answer. Not very high-quality, so you should consider adding an explanation of your code, etc.

Comment: @Nick, again curious.  Why do you say "not very high quality" - do you mean the code, or just the overall presentation?  (ps - point taken on lack of explanation, but I'd been speaking in the comments.  Should have moved some of that over with my anser)

Comment: It's not considered a high-quality answer when you only provide code and do not provide any explanation.

Comment: @Nick - cool. I see your point, and agree.  Thanks for the feedback.